# CSS: Is it possible to draw a triangle at the width of the screensize with static height

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with responsive triangles - I need to create a triangle that fits the screen width but it's width doesn't change when screen width is made smaller.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Does it need to fit screen on initial load and not change after that even if the screen sizze changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with a solution that adds two triangles (each with a width of 50%) and by using a linear-gradient:

```css
#triangle {
  overflow: auto;
}

#triangle span {
  width:50%;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

#triangle span:first-child {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, orange 50%, transparent 50%);
}

#triangle span:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, orange 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle">
  <span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

To make the triangle keep the initial width, you could add the following js:

```
var triangle = document.getElementById('triangle');
var width = triangle.offsetWidth;
triangle.style.setProperty('width', width+"px");
```

[See the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb2msbca/) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
background-size: 100% 150px;
```